# Call Android App from Other App and receiving Data with getLaunchIntentForPackage

Tags: android

I have 2 Android apps, App myapp.a and App myapp.b

I want to call myapp.a from myapp.b using startActivityForResult, sending an id to myapp.b and receiving data from myapp.b using setResult.

i can call myapp.b and passing the parameter, but onActivityResult is called with Activity.RESULT_CANCELED directly after starting the myapp.b and i dont understand why. Here is my code:

myapp.a:

```
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i= getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("myapp.b");
            i.putExtra("id", 1);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.w("onAResultCalled", "Code:" + resultCode);
}
```

myapp.b:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_appb);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Log.w("ID", "Called id:" + i.getIntExtra("id", -1));

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i= new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("resultdata", "mydata");
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

The myapp.b starts correctly and is getting the right id, but onActivityResult will be called without pressing the button. When i press the Button on myapp.b the app closed, but onActivityResult is not called on app.a

Has anyone an idea whats wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your  in your AndroidManifest files are incorrect.

Or appB crashes and you may have error logs ?